# Database back-up as cronjob

Tags: mysql, shell

I use this command to create .sql files of all tables in a huge mysql database:

`mysqldump -h localhost --user=username -p  --tab=/var/tmp  database_name`

The command above works perfectly but is prompting for the password.

Before i run this command i need to run:

`GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'username'@'%'`

otherwise i get the error:

`Got error: 1086: "File '/var/tmp/a_ab_text.txt' already exists" when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'`

a_ab_text is the first table of the database.
Is there a way to get around this as I need to create a script that can be daily run as a cronjob.
To be clear a need a way to have the password in the script but typing the password after the `--password '********'` does not work.

And i need a way to overwrite the tables every day as we export all tables daily to a local server giving timestamp to the back-up file in order to have a dayly back-up version.

And of course i need a way to get around the command `GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'username'@'%'` and restart the mysql server.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried --password=password as it says in the manual?

Comment: Do you mean `--password=********`  ?

Comment: Depends - if your password is 'password', but I think the idea of putting your password in is the idea.

Comment: yes it is , i nee to have the password in script